# Undo modified files in git does not work

Tags: git

I have modified files in my git repo, but `git checkout <file>` does not work and neither does `git reset --hard`. There are no error messages whatsoever. I also have one *.orig and `git clean -f` does not remove that file either?

Comment: Did you do a `merge` and you failed? Or, are you in the middle of a `merge`?

Comment: @Atropo maybe I have merged and not committed because the files seems to be staged. But I thought I could reset staged files using `git reset HEAD <file>`?

Comment: post the output of `git status`

Comment: `git status -s
 M README.md
 M src/NKA.Core/Domain/PageTypes/AreaPage.cs.orig
 M src/NKA.Web/App_Browsers/AdapterMappings.browser
 M src/NKA.Web/App_Browsers/IE6.browser
 M src/NKA.Web/Templates/ArticleList.aspx
 M src/NKA.Web/Templates/Page.aspx`

Comment: Do you want to reverty the changes? Try these : `git checkout -- <filename>` or `git reset --hard origin/master` or `git reset --hard origin/[branch-name]`

Answer (score 2):

If `git checkout` and `git reset --hard` are leaving files in a modified state, it can be caused by git modifying line-endings or whitespace.

Run `git diff --ignore-space-change` to see if there are non-whitespace changes.

If the *.orig file is not tracked by git, but is **ignored**, you must add the `-x` parameter so that git doesn't use the standard ignore rules.

```
git clean -f -x
```

Comment: `git clean` only removes untracked files, but `git status` shows that the file is tracked. The modified status is definitely whitespace, see [Dealing with line endings](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings).

Comment: Ok, how can I reset modified tracked files from my local repo?

Comment: you are correct, I use both os x and windows in this repo so I emailed github and they told me to put `*text=auto` in my `.gitattributes`file but if I remove that line again my changed are gone. Maybe this is off topic but what is the best settings for line endings when working on both os x and windows?

Comment: GitHub recommends `git config --global core.autocrlf input` on OS X and `git config --global core.autocrlf true` on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

try this out.

i think the file is in staged section.

first do

```
   git reset HEAD <file>...
```

then do

```
  git checkout <file>...
```

Answer (score 0):

To me looks like you're in the middle of a `merge`, that's why you have the `.orig` files. Diff tools create `.orig` files to keep a backup of merged files.

If you want to abort the merge you can do, but only if you have git >= 1.6.1

```
git reset --merge
```

Or, starting from version 1..7.4, you do:

```
git merge --abort
```